# Subversion: svn protocol with HTTP/HTTPS proxy

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I need to do a svn checkout,say

```
svn checkout svn://XYZ.com/trunk.
```

I am using the svn client from behind the proxy. I had accessed other repositries using the http protocol in past but with svn protocol,it fails with "Connection Refused", reason I think being the port not allowed by the proxy.Nonetheless, the HTTP protocol is not supported on the server.

However, svn+ssh gets connected but it prompts for an account at that server which I don't have?

Is there any way out other than requesting for an account?

Note that I can't affect the settings of the proxy server.

Comment: HTTP proxies probably do not deal with traffic to svn server ports. If everything else but http is denied to you could tunnel your traffic through the Tor network that uses http(s) ports for its entry nodes.

Comment: yea i was thinking of something alike, may be corkscrew but not sure how too use it with svn

Answer (score 1):

SVN creates a file that on Windows is called "C:\Documents and Settings\mjohansen\Application Data\Subversion\servers". (I'm not sure where it goes on Linux off the top of my head.) This file contains a number of configuration parameters, including "http-proxy-host", "http-proxy-port", etc. By default they are commented out. You can uncomment them and fill in your proxy information.

I presume this only applies to certain SVN clients. But I find that this same file is used by the standard SVN command line app, Tortoise, and the Eclipse Subclipse SVN plug-in.

All this assumes that your problem is indeed proxy servers.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your question then.

Comment: in linux it goes to ~/.subversion/servers